# Bash error - cut: the delimiter must be a single character (trying to use "/")

Tags: bash, delimiter

I'm trying to use a forward slash as a delimiter but I'm getting the error:

> cut: the delimiter must be a single character

This is my command:

```
cat index.html |grep “href=“ |cut -d”/“ -f3 |more
```

Comment: Neither `html=` nor `/` need to be quoted in a bash word. So you could juzt remove the quotes, or you could fix them. In the secons xase, I'd suggest making them single quotes.

Comment: But if you're quoting, do read the bash man page to understand the difference in behavior between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suspect you're pasting high-ascii (fancy unicode) double-quotes there.

compare:

```
$ echo cut -d”/“ | hexdump -C
00000000  63 75 74 20 2d 64 e2 80  9d 2f e2 80 9c 0a        |cut -d.../....|
0000000e

$ echo cut -d"/" | hexdump -C
00000000  63 75 74 20 2d 64 2f 0a                           |cut -d/.|
00000008
```

`2f` is the (forward) slash, which is all you want `cut` to see for its `-d` argument. Note that in the second expression, bash doesn't send the actual double quotes to the command at all, which is your goal.

`e2 80 9d 2f e2 80 9c` is `e2 80 9d` + `2f` + `e2 80 9c`. `e2 80 9d` (`11100010 10000000 10011101` in binary) is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for `U+201d` and `e2 80 9c` is UTF-8 for `U+201c`, which are [right double quotation mark](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=201D) and [left double quotation mark](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=201C), respectively. It's interesting that your paste resulted in having them "inside-out" -- that is //x\\ rather than \\x//.

The low-ascii double-quote that bash *does* strip is `22` (hex, or 34 in decimal), which in unicode parlance is `U+0022` ([quotation mark](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0022)).

I'd highly recommend reading the "QUOTING" section of Bash's manual page (`man bash` and search for QUOTING (type `/QUOTING` + Enter), then scroll with up and down arrow keys, and `q` to quit)

Comment: Note that in your second hexdump, the double quotes are being stripped out by the command interpreter. To demonstrate, try: `for n in 63 75 74 20 2d 64 2f 0a; do printf "\x$n"; done; echo`. (You probably already know this, but other readers might not.)